# Why nerdcommenter is not working for me

Tags: vim

I am using macvim with pathogen. This is what I have in my vimrc

```
filetype off

call pathogen#runtime_append_all_bundles()

syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
set tabstop=2
set smarttab
set shiftwidth=2
set autoindent
set expandtab
```

I have nerd_commenter installed in my bundle directory.

When I open a .js file and I hit 4 , space then 4 lines are not commented.

I noticed that nerd_commenter has following lines of code

```
\ 'javascript': { 'left': '//', 'leftAlt': '/*', 'rightAlt': '*/' },
\ 'javascript.jquery': { 'left': '//', 'leftAlt': '/*', 'rightAlt': '*/' }
```

I guess by having filetype plugin indent on macvim should be able to figure that I am operating on a Javascript file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never mind I needed to do leader c space.